# Right way to define NSManagedObjectContext?

Tags: macos, swift, core-data

Earlier in my apps with `CoreData` I used to define my `NSManagedObjectContext` this way:

```
class MyViewController: NSViewController {

    lazy var moc: NSManagedObjectContext? = {
        let app = NSApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
        if let moc = app.managedObjectContext {
            return moc
        } else {
            return nil
        }
    }()

    // ....
}
```

But then I downloaded Apple's sample app called `Eartquakes` and there `NSManagedObjectContext` was like that:

```
import Cocoa

class CoreDataStackManager {

    class var sharedManager: CoreDataStackManager {
        struct Singleton {
            static let coreDataStackManager = CoreDataStackManager()
        }
        return Singleton.coreDataStackManager
    }

    // persistenStoreCoordinator etc...
```

And in ViewController:

```
class ApplesViewController: NSViewController {

    private lazy var managedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext = {
        let moc = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: .MainQueueConcurrencyType)

        moc.persistentStoreCoordinator = CoreDataStackManager.sharedManager.persistentStoreCoordinator

        return moc
    }()
}
```

So I just wondering which way is the right way - I assume that is Apple's way :) - and that why the Core Data Stack is defined in AppDelegate by default?

Comment: I think it's cleaner to have a smallest possible AppDelegate, and specific manager.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do this but in the end it comes to maintainability.

The best way that I have found and it goes with Apple's traditional approach to other items is:

1. Create a separate controller for Core Data.
2. Initialize that controller in the AppDelegate.
3. Use Dependency Injection to pass that controller into the view controllers.

DO NOT use a Singleton.  While it feels easy at the start of a project it tends to paint you into a corner later.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, that Dependency Injection is new word for me, have to Google it now :)

Comment: It just means that the object that exists passes a reference to the object that was just created.  AppDelegate passes reference to RootViewController, RootViewController passes to the next view controller, etc.  Not a very complex concept.